# Stuck!.. a mix of segmentation fault, qsort_r, arrays, pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-leaks, qsort

I hope i made it short and clear what I'm trying to do below.

The code is pretty complex for a SOF question and i didn't think i could make it simpler while keeping it directly testable by others.

so i cut the relevant parts and put them here.

why do i get this error and can you help me to fix it?

any help is appreciated!

thank you.

```
    char words[100][WORD_LENGTH];

    char temp[WORD_LENGTH];

    // scan the next %s from stream and put it to temp
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", temp) > 0){
        // printf("reducer reads: %s\n", temp);

        strcpy(words[arr_i], temp);
        printf("%d -- %s\n", arr_i, words[arr_i]);

        arr_i++;

    }
```

at the second line i get segmentation fault error. (and possibly leak with valgrind)

```
    int thunk = WORD_LENGTH; 
    qsort_r(&words, sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]), sizeof(words[0]), cmpstringp, &thunk);
```

from "man qsort":

```
static int cmpstringp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
   /* The actual arguments to this function are "pointers to
      pointers to char", but strcmp(3) arguments are "pointers
      to char", hence the following cast plus dereference */

   return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `WORD_LENGTH`?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo #define WORD_LENGTH 255

Comment: Have you verified your "words" array for valid (length, null-termination) strings?

Comment: @EugeneSh. strings are valid, and before strcpy program prints them correctly.

Comment: I understand that you were trying to show only the relevant parts of a complicated program, but the problem is very likely to be in code you have not shown us. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then, as directed there, attempt to construct the smallest possible *complete program* that *still exhibits the same crash*.  You may discover the bug for yourself in this process.

Comment: Are you sure you're filling the 100  positions of the array? Since you're using `sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0])` in the qsort, that is, (255*100)/255.  You should use `arr_i` just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per `man qsort`:

> The qsort_r() function is identical to qsort() except that the
>   comparison function compar takes a third argument

Your comparison function is taking two arguments.

**Update**: And the real crash reason is following. You are passing to the compare function elements of array of type `char[WORD_LENGTH]`, not `char*` as in `man qsort` example. So the parameters passed to the comparison function are p1 = &words[_], which is a pointer to the string to be compared. While in the case of char pointers it would be `(char **)`, just a pointer to a `char`/string pointer. So the casts in the line`strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);` are unnecessary and harmful, because in your case the leftmost dereference is the cause of the problem. Remove them and leave just `strcmp(p1, p2)`. 

 As a side note, this issue is emphasizing again the difference between string array declarations as `char *[]` and `char [][]`.

Comment: I don't understand... I copied that function from man qsort manual.

Comment: Oh, thank you. So I should change to  `static int cmpstringp(const void *p1, const void *p2, void *p3)` and just not use p3. Right?

Comment: Why do you need the third argument? You can use just `qsort`.

Comment: I feel like I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: You should make that change, yes, but this almost certainly isn't the true cause of the crash.  (Or you could just use regular old `qsort`; you don't appear to *need* the context parameter for anything.)

Comment: It's not THAT context.

Comment: @user4220128 `qsort` itself is thread-safe as long as the comparison function only needs to access the two elements to compare.  `qsort_r` is for passing in extra data when necessary.  Your comparison function is safe for use with plain `qsort` even in the presence of threads.

Comment: @user4220128 ... I guess `qsort` would also not be thread-safe if you tried to sort the same array from two threads at the same time, but that is true of `qsort_r` as well.